# adding username and password error message

Tags: php, mysql

I want to add a an error message if the user entered the wrong username or password.  Currently if a username or password is wrong it just reloads the login page with no error.

Comment: I can't see any error messages given. Even you should  write a else condition with an error message at all

Comment: @jacob Please see my answer. I have provided a link for a simple tutorial from creating table in the database, creating a HTML to PHP Script.

Answer (score 0):

Just modify your if statement to see if they had a successful login:

```
if( mysql_num_rows( $login) == 1) 
{
    // Successful login
    $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];
    ...
}
else
{
    // Invalid login
    echo "Your username or password are incorrect!";
}
```

Comment: can you check if i have done it right and edit if necessary: http://pastebin.com/V1urcqBe

Comment: @Jacob - It looks like you'll need something like this: http://pastebin.com/c9awk0X4

Comment: i have edited my main post above as there was more to follow. maybe missing a brace

Answer (score 0):

```
if(mysql_num_rows($login) == 1)
{
$SESSION['username'=$_POST['username'];

//Successfull login  redirect to home page
}
else
{
// incorrect username or password
$incorrectLogin_flag =1;
}
```

**then in html**

```
<?php

echo "Username : <input type='text' name='username' />";

echo "Username : <input type='password' name='password' />";

echo " <input type='submit' value='Login' />";

echo " <input type='submit' value='Cancel' />";

if($incorrectLogin_flag ==1)
{
 echo" <label style='color:red;'> Username or Password incorrect.</label>";
}
```

?>

Answer (score 0):

Use else,

```
    if(Something goes wrong){

    //display the errors


    }elseif(all goes right){
    //login
    //redirect


    }
```

No need to give you the full code you can google it.

Answer (score 0):

this may be the basic tutorial to create a simple validation using php and mysql.

[REFERENCE for PHP Login script tutorial](http://phpeasystep.com/phptu/6.html)

**Sample Code Snippet:**

```
<?php
$host="localhost"; // Host name 
$username=""; // Mysql username 
$password=""; // Mysql password 
$db_name="test"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="members"; // Table name

// Connect to server and select databse.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

// username and password sent from form 
$myusername=$_POST['myusername']; 
$mypassword=$_POST['mypassword'];

// To protect MySQL injection (more detail about MySQL injection)
$myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
$mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);
$myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($myusername);
$mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($mypassword);

$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE username='$myusername' and password='$mypassword'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

// Mysql_num_row is counting table row
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);
// If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row

if($count==1){
// Register $myusername, $mypassword and redirect to file "login_success.php"
session_register("myusername");
session_register("mypassword"); 
header("location:login_success.php");
}
else {
echo "Wrong Username or Password";
}
?>
```